# Does stdafx need to be in the same directory?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I have a separate folder for my includes because its a part of a larger application, but I use precompiled headers to save time. However, that means I need 2 or more separate stdafx considering I am these standard libraries in my header files as well.

Comment: Not having worked with VS for some time, I think that the `stdafx.h` header file has to be in the same file as the `stdafx.cpp` source file. I don't remember how much of these paths you can change, but you should be able to change some of them in the project settings.

Comment: I've succesfully used `#include "../stdafx.h"` as the only line in nested stdafx.h files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not working correctly. Your own header files should NEVER reference "stdafx.h". Instead, they may safely assume that it is already included.

If you've got multiple projects in your solution, each in their own directory, then each project can contain a separate `stdafx.h` without problems.

Comment: what if you have variables that contain type from stdafx?

Comment: For instance D3DXVECTOR3 or  ID3D10ShaderResourceView

Comment: I have expanded the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856420/does-stdafx-need-to-be-in-the-same-directory Please take a look if you can.

Comment: @mk1: Your header is always included after stdafx.h, since that is the first header included in each .cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this answers your question, but you can right click on `stdafx.cpp` in the solution explorer, then select Precompiled Headers. In the line Precompiled header file, you can enter the complete path to `stdafx.h`.

Or open the project file and after

```
<ClCompile Include="stdafx.cpp">
  <PrecompiledHeader>Create</PrecompiledHeader>
```

insert

```
  <PrecompiledHeaderFile>otherDirectory\stdafx.h</PrecompiledHeaderFile>
```